# Dynamically, check radio button with for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a 5 star radio picker.

This is the 1 of the radio buttons:

```
<input onclick="check(3)" type="radio" name="three" id="num_3_star" value="3">
```

After the method gets called and "3" is passed on this is my javascript function:

```
function check(stars)
{
    for(i = 0 ; i < stars; i++)
    {       
        document.getElementById("num_" + stars + "_star").checked = true;
    }   
}
```

When I run the code, it does not perform the checked to = true, though if remove the for loop, it works just fine.

Any ideas why the for loop is preventing from checking the radio boxes?

This is my entire code:

```
<script>
function check(stars)
{
    for(i = 0 ; i < stars; i++)
    {       
        document.getElementById("num_" + stars + "_star").checked = true;
    }   
}
</script>

<form>
<input onclick="check(1)" type="radio" name="one" id="num_1_star" value="1">
<input onclick="check(2)" type="radio" name="two" id="num_2_star" value="2">
<input onclick="check(3)" type="radio" name="three" id="num_3_star" value="3">
<input onclick="check(4)" type="radio" name="four" id="num_4_star" value="4">
<input onclick="check(5)" type="radio" name="five" id="num_5_star" value="5">
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: They must be having same name for radio buttons..Radio buttons is not the ideal element here!

Comment: Changing the name does not help. I'm using radio button for programming sake. :) I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do it.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or entire code of yours ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `i` had to be **1** initially as `ids` are starting from **1**
>
> Also reset all the `checked` status when click is initiated! Use `i` instead of `stars` in `getElementById`

Try this:

```js
function check(stars) {

  for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
 document.getElementById("num_" + j + "_star").checked = false;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= stars; i++) {
    document.getElementById("num_" + i + "_star").checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input onclick="check(1)" type="radio" name="one" id="num_1_star" value="1">
<input onclick="check(2)" type="radio" name="two" id="num_2_star" value="2">
<input onclick="check(3)" type="radio" name="three" id="num_3_star" value="3">
<input onclick="check(4)" type="radio" name="four" id="num_4_star" value="4">
<input onclick="check(5)" type="radio" name="five" id="num_5_star" value="5">
```

Comment: Perfect! That was mas problem... It was initialized to 0 and it should of been 1. Thanks brother :) + Thanks for the additional code that I was missing. Wanted to figure it out myself but oh well hahaha. I just post here when I am completely exhausted xD

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz, also the key thing is, pass parameter as 'i' instead of 'stars' in document.getElementById("num_" + i + "_star")

Comment: Oh hahaha bummer. That was the main reason. I feel so dumb right now. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Put `var` before the iteration variable `i`. You are creating a global variable.